# Code that changes the users input to lower case

Tags: python

There is a piece of code that changes anything the user inputs to lower case, how would I implement this into my code instead of using ["a" or "A"]?

```
def displaymenu():
    print("Weather station")
    print("Please enter the option you would like")
    optionchoice = input("Please enter A,B,C or D:")

    if optionchoice in ["a" or "A"]:
        print("The temperature will be displayed")
        time.sleep(1)
        optionA()

    elif optionchoice in ["b" or "B"]:
        print("The wind speed will be displayed")
        time.sleep(1)
        optionB()

    elif optionchoice in ["c" or "C"]:
        print("The day and time will be displayed")
        time.sleep(1)
        optionC()

    elif optionchoice in ["d" or "D"]:
        print("The Location will be displayed")
        time.sleep(1)
        optionD()

    else:
        print("Please type a valid input")
        displaymenu()
```

Comment: You could use `.lower()` to force it lower case

Comment: How would i put this into my code, I'm not entirely sure

Comment: `optionchoice = input("Please enter A,B,C or D:").lower()`

Comment: Thank you but on a sub program optionB(), it says 'expected a indented block'

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

`optionchoice = input("Please enter A,B,C or D:").lower()`

This way you are forcing the input to the lowercase version of whatever the user types.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Python has a built in method:

For example:

```
string = "ABCDabcd123"
lowercase = string.lower()
print(lowercase)
```

will give you abcdabcd123 !

Try it out and find more about it here: 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_lower.htm

Answer (score 0):

if you use python 2 you should use `raw_input().lower()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [str.lower()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.lower#str.lower) method, you could make changes to your code like so:

```
def displaymenu():
    print("Weather station")
    print("Please enter the option you would like")

    optionchoice = input("Please enter A, B, C or D: ").lower() # Convert input to lowercase.

    if optionchoice == 'a':
        print("The temperature will be displayed")
        time.sleep(1)
        optionA()

    elif optionchoice == 'b':
        print("The wind speed will be displayed")
        time.sleep(1)
        optionB()

    elif optionchoice == 'c':
        print("The day and time will be displayed")
        time.sleep(1)
        optionC()

    elif optionchoice == 'd':
        print("The Location will be displayed")
        time.sleep(1)
        optionD()

    else:
        print("Please type a valid input")
        displaymenu()
```

If for some  reason you want to stick with your version, validate the input like so:

```
if optionchoice in ['a', 'A']:
```